# Clojure: Deploying on Clojars and later Require

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen, clojars

I have a basic question regarding deployment to Clojars.  I wrote a library and deployed it to Clojars, but when I try to require it, I receive a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

Here is how I am requiring it:

https://github.com/mobiusinversion/interval-trees

and here is where it is on Clojars:

https://clojars.org/interval-trees

I think maybe I am missing something with respect to group or artifact ids, I'm not sure.  I would appreciate help in having this go out.  Thanks!

The way I am testing this is in a new lein project called interval-tree-test.  Here is my project.clj for that test:

```
(defproject interval-tree-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [interval-trees "0.2.3"]]
  :main interval-tree-test.core)
```

Now when I run lein deps I get

```
$ lein deps
Retrieving interval-trees/interval-trees/0.2.3/interval-trees-0.2.3.pom from clojars
Retrieving interval-trees/interval-trees/0.2.3/interval-trees-0.2.3.jar from clojars
```

And sure enough in my .m2 directory

```
$ ls ~/.m2/repository/interval-trees/interval-trees/0.2.3/  
interval-trees-0.2.3.jar.sha1    interval-trees-0.2.3.pom.sha1
interval-trees-0.2.3.jar         interval-trees-0.2.3.pom
```

And finally in my core.clj

```
(ns interval-tree-test.core
    (:gen-class)
    (:require [interval-trees.interval-tree :as it]))

    (defn -main [& args] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `require` form is wrong. There are two ways to solve this:

- You can move the `:require` form into the `ns` form:

  ```
  (ns interval-tree-test.core
    (:require [interval-trees.interval-tree :as it])))
  ```
- You can use the [`require`](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/require) function to do it without a `ns` form:

  ```
  (require '[interval-trees.interval-tree :as it])) ;; note the quote
  ```

I don't know why/how using `:gen-class` would have helped you fix that, though.

Comment: Hey thanks for the heads up.  I fixed that in the note and the code.  For some reason the solution came when I added (:gen-class) flags to all namespaces in the project.  I need to find out more about thwy that is. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I sprinkled :gen-class in all my .clj in interval-trees and it worked.  Dont get it but glad its done.